# Weird Safari behaviour!

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, font

Today safari (v11.1) on Mac HighSierra 10.13.4, started to behave like crazy. For some reasons this is the resolution I get everytime I open the browser. Looks a kind of mobile resolution. I restarted, erased the history, changed from view --> font in, font out, but  nothing happens.

Here a screenshot:
 [image: Weird layout]

What should I do? Now I am writing from Chrome.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) If you have Develop menu enabled, go to Develop → User Agent and check if it's set to default. Develop menu is shown between Bookmarks and Window menu.

Comment: If you don't see the Develop menu, you can turn it on from Safari Preferences by clicking the `Advanced` tab, then enabling `Show Develop menu in menu bar`. (Although, if it's not already enabled, chances are you've never modified your UA string.)

Comment: is it specific to german language setting

Answer (score 1):

I checked develop → User Agent and check if it's set to default. When I switch to some options, it reloads correctly and then goes back to the same view.